# String to CLOB with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, clob

I'm trying to read a clob from postgreSQL DB, change it, and write it back.

I was able to read the clob successfully using the following code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT clob_column from data where id = 1");
ResultSet executeQuery = statement.executeQuery();
executeQuery.next()
Clob fetchedClob = executeQuery.getClob("clob_column");
```

But when I'm trying to create a new clob with the new data using:

```
Clob newClob = connection.createClob();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob;
```

Moreover, If I try just to edit the fetched clob, using:

```
fetchedClob.setString(0, "new string");
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Clob.setString(long,str) is not yet implemented.
```

Any idea?

**Update: here is the table definition**

> CREATE TABLE data (
>       id bigint NOT NULL,
>       clob_column text, );

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use `getClob()`.

`ResultSet.getString()` and `setString()` work perfectly fine on `text` columns (PostgreSQL does not have a `clob` datatype so I assume you are using `text`)

Comment: I am using text.
When I tried to use getString I get back a number which I don't understand its meaning (maybe the actual data length?).
Only when I do getClob and look at its character stream (getCharacterStream) I get the full XML which is saved in the DB.

Comment: @BenBracha: Then you are not showing us everything. `getString()` definitely works fine with `text`columns. Please show us your table definition (edit your question).

Comment: Updated above.
I now also see that org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Clob which is used by my application doesn't implement all set* for Clob.
What should I do?

Also I should add we use Hibernate, and the matching entity for this table has it column_text field marked with @Lob

Comment: @BenBracha: I don't know Hibernate. But if you don't get the correct value using `getString()` then there is something wrong with your program. The JDBC driver works correctly (you **are** using a current version, are you?)

Comment: @BenBracha: I have seen several discussion regarding Hibernate and CLOB columns. Why don't you simply annotate it as `String` (if that exists)? Then Hibernate should use `getString()`. Another option might be to annotate it as `Clob`(if there is such a thing)

Comment: There is no such annotations I'm aware of. Can you FW me to those discussions?

Comment: @BenBracha: There is no `String` annotation?? How do you annotate regular `varchar` columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres does have a Clob data type now.